# How to parse and pull data from json post in create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Below is the JSON I am feeding my create method in my controller

```
{
   "sex":null,
   "money":281,
   "networth":281,
   "property":[
      {
         "houses":"1",
         "id":"5",
         "father":"Jerry",
         "mother":"Tanya",
         "height":281,
         "children":2,
         "pets":24
      },
      {
         "houses":"3",
         "id":"5",
         "father":"Rob",
         "mother":"Anne",
         "height":726,
         "children":1,
         "pets":55
      }
   ]
}
```

My controller below:

```
  def create
     person = Person.new
     person.houses = person_params[:houses]
     person.father = person_params[:father]
     person.save
  end


  private

   def person_params
    params.permit(person: []).require(:person)
   end
```

I am having trouble finding how to pull out data from the JSON passed, lets say i want to save instances of houses or any other value in the array in the JSON, how would i pull out that data? I think i am having trouble with my person_params

Answer (score 0):

you need to format your json format as follow

```
{ "person": { "money": "281", "address": "123 Carrot Street" } }
```

your create method will received params with this format

```
params[:person] as { "money" => "281", "address" => "123 Carrot Street" }
```

and this is [link document for official guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#json-parameters)